# Can MySQL return true/false to use directly in Elastic Search

Tags: mysql

In Elastic Search a field is defined as boolean. The data to fill it comes directly from MySQL. This gives an error because Elastic does not accept 0 and 1 as booleans. Can I have MySQL return false/true instead, because I do not want to manipulate the data in PHP first.

I have seen solutions like:

```
IF(field_name, 'true', 'false') AS field_name
```

This however returns a string and not a boolean.

Is there a solutions for this?

Comment: I never used Elastic Search but by googling I found here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/boolean.html this: *Boolean fields accept JSON true and false values, but can also accept strings which are interpreted as either true or false*. So maybe strings will work.

Comment: For selections in ES it might work fine, but the code using the ES does not accept "false" and "true" as correct boolean. So left or right it seems I need to add some code somewhere to handle this "bug" in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the Elastic Search documentation:

> Boolean fields accept JSON true and false values, but can also accept
>   strings which are interpreted as either true or false

Furthermore:

```
False values - false, "false"
True values - true, "true"
```

Therefore, returning a string from MySQL containing the word `true` or `false` should work happily.

For reference, here is the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/boolean.html).

Comment: For selections in ES it might work fine, but the code using the ES does not accept "false" and "true" as correct boolean. So left or right it seems I need to add some code somewhere to handle this "bug" in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately MySQL still does not have "native" boolean, you will either need to return a string or use 0/1 instead.